# Resize menu when scrolling down

Tags: css, wordpress-theming

I'm currently restyling my Wordpress theme and would like to implement a fixed navbar. I managed to implement that by adding position:fixed to the header area.

Since the menu is quite big in the first place, I would like to make it smaller when scrolling down, i.e. when the user visits the website, the menu has a height of 75px and when scrolling down it decreases to around 40-50px.

Quick sketch: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWL8c.png

Any suggestions on how I may implement this?

Cheers,
Philipp

Answer (score 1):

Since you're asking about WordPress I guess you're OK with using jQuery.
You just need to listen for the `$(window).scroll()` event and resize the menu based on how much the user has scrolled (which you can get via `$(window).scrollTop()`). A quick demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/FMypW/1/

(it's not an actual menu, but just showing the functionality work)

Comment: I'd suggest adding and removing a class rather than editing the CSS within jQuery. I assume changing the height wont be enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
var moved = false;

$(window).scroll(function(){ 

    if( $(this).scrollTop() < 2000 ){
        $('.header').height(200 - (200 * $(this).scrollTop() / $('body').height()));

        if (!moved && $('.header').height() < 170)
        {
            $('.header').animate({top:"-40px"});     moved = true;  
        } else if (moved && $('.header').height() > 170)
        {
            $('.header').animate({top:"0px"});       moved = false;
        }

    }

});
```

### And here's the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KUTGS/)

Additionally, you might want to check out these tutorials instead of inventing the wheel yourself:

> - [How to create a resizing menu bar](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/03/how-to-create-a-resizing-menu-bar/)
> - [Animated Resizing Header On Scroll](http://www.callmenick.com/2014/02/18/create-an-animated-resizing-header-on-scroll/)